# Get selected row on right mouse click in Kendo Grid

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a Kendo Grid and I want to detect the right click and left click, so based on these I do two separate things. I used to get ID from the grid on either left or right click before and was working fine. But to fix an IE11 clicking problem I had to update the kendo.js to 2013.2.716 version and after that it detects left/right click all right but for "Right Click" can't get the selected row Id. The following is my code to detect left/right click and PlodId is a column in my grid:

```
function LoadMainShiftGrid() {

//For Right Click --> Delete Selected Shift

$("#shiftReport").delegate("tbody>tr", "contextmenu", function (e) {
    if (e.which == 3) {
        $("#plodDetails").hide();            
        var gridData = $('#shiftReport').data("kendoGrid");
        var selectedRowData = gridData.dataItem($('.k-grid').find("tr.k-state-selected"));

    // MY PROBLEM FOR RIGHT CLICK SELECTEDROWDATA COMES TO NULL <<<<

        var SelectedPlodId = selectedRowData.PlodId;                        
    }
});

//For Left Click --> Show Plod Detials

$("#shiftReport").delegate("tbody>tr", "click", function (e) {
    if (e.which == 1) {
        var gridData = $('#shiftReport').data("kendoGrid");
        var selectedRowData = gridData.dataItem($('.k-grid').find("tr.k-state-selected"));
        var SelectedPlodId = selectedRowData.PlodId;           
    }
});
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've changed the click binding function to 'mousedown' and select the row manually (Thank you @drw85 for the idea) and after that it works fine.

```
function LoadMainShiftGrid() {

$('#shiftReport').data('kendoGrid').tbody.on('mousedown', function (e) {

    //select the clicked row manually; this resolves all problem :D
    $('#shiftReport').data("kendoGrid").select(e.target.parentElement);

   if (e.which == 3) {
        $("#plodDetails").hide();            
        var gridData = $('#shiftReport').data("kendoGrid");
        var selectedRowData = gridData.dataItem($('.k-grid').find("tr.k-state-selected"));    
        var SelectedPlodId = selectedRowData.PlodId;                        
    }

    //For Left Click --> Show Plod Details    
    if (e.which == 1) {
        var gridData = $('#shiftReport').data("kendoGrid");
        var selectedRowData = gridData.dataItem($('.k-grid').find("tr.k-state-selected"));
        var SelectedPlodId = selectedRowData.PlodId;           
    }
});
}
```

Comment: May i know what is #shiftReport?

Comment: @UserA1195 its the HTML id where you will gonna hook the kendo grid.

Answer (score 1):

I think that happens, because the right click doesn't actually select the row.
You can select it through code, before you try to get it via

```
var selectedRowData = gridData.dataItem($('.k-grid').find("tr.k-state-selected"));
```

You should be able to get the click target through the event object and set the selected property on it via kendo.

```
var index = gridData.find(e.delegateTarget).index(); 
var dataItem = gridData.dataSource.view()[index]; 
dataItem.selected();
```

You might have to pass true to the selected function.

Comment: If you can provide a jsfiddle with an example, i will have another look.

Comment: hmmn.. thank you for your help.. it didn't work "in js it said, has no method 'find'".. but from your idea i've come up with the solution.

Comment: Well, edit your question with the solution, so others can learn from it. ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can also get the selected row like this..

```
$("#shiftReport").on("mousedown", "tr[role='row']", function (e) {
    if (e.which === 3) {
        $(this).addClass("k-state-selected");
         var gview= $('#shiftReport').data("kendoGrid");
        var selectedRow = gview.dataItem($(this));
      }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use .Selectable() will high light the row when you hover over rows and click on any particular row, sample code:

```
    @(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model)
          .Name("Grid")
          .DataSource(datasource => datasource
              .Ajax()
              .ServerOperation(false)
              .PageSize(15)
              )
            .Sortable()
            .Columns(columns =>
            {
                columns.Bound(model => model.NetworkID);
                columns.Bound(model => model.FirstName);
                columns.Bound(model => model.LastName);
            })
            .Filterable()
            .Scrollable(s => s.Height(550))
            .Pageable()
            .Resizable(resize => resize.Columns(true))
            .Selectable()
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

In IE 11 this will work

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
change: function(e) {
var selected = this.select();
var selectedDataItems = [];
for (var i = 0; i < selected.length; i++) {
  var dataItem = this.dataItem($(selected[i]).closest("tr"));
  selectedDataItems.push(dataItem);
}
}
});
```